# FireFox Tails Verification

Tags: tails, firefox

Why FireFox not support Tails verification,anyone with answer?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are hitting this known bug: https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/12328

Firefox 57 no longer runs the type of "legacy extension" that Tails Download and Verify is. (Can it be overridden with a flag somehow, or has that time come and gone?)

By the way, your image link is messed up. It should be https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EFHE.jpg